# Return value of Reap when using tags

Tags: list-manipulation

I've noticed a behaviour of `Reap` that I don't quite understand yet.
Suppose I want to `Sow` several values during a computation.

```
sowstuff := (Do[Sow[i, tag1], {i, 5}]; Do[Sow[i^2, tag2], {i, 5}])
```

If I `Reap` this, I get one list of values per tag.

```
Reap[sowstuff] // Last
-> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}}
```

[image: TreeForm of plain Reap]

If I specify the tags i want to use explicitly, each of these lists gets wrapped in an additional list:

```
Reap[sowstuff, {tag1, tag2}] // Last
-> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}}}
```

[image: TreeForm of Reap with explicit tags]

I believe I understand how `Reap` in general works. What puzzles me is the purpose of this additional wrapping. After reading the documentation of `Reap` and `Sow`, I have not yet seen a situation in which this list contains more than one element.

So my questions are:

- Is there a reason for the introduction of another list?
- Can this list have more than one element or is it always safe to just run `Map[First,%]` to remove it?

Comment: Interesting. Up to this point, I had not found the second argument of `Reap` useful; I will have to re-evaluate my opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate sublists with more than one element.  For example:

```
Last @ Reap[
  Sow[1,a]; Sow[2,a]
; Sow[3,b]; Sow[4,b]
; Sow[5,c]; Sow[6,c]
; Sow[7,d]; Sow[8,d]
, {a|b, c|d}
]

(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}} *)
```

The documentation explains that this happens because "Expressions sown using [...] different tags are given in different lists."  It also states that we specify a list of patterns, the results for each pattern is returned in a separate list.  This explains the  extra levels of list structure.

---

**Rant**

*enter at your own risk :)*

Personally, I find `Reap` to be over-general.  It irritates me that the shape of the result is different when no values are sown, e.g.

```
Reap[Sow[1]] // Last
(* {{1}} *)
```

But:

```
Reap[Null] // Last
(* {} *)
```

For me, building a single list of results is the common case.  I'm usually not interested in value of the expression either -- just the list being built.  So, most of the time my `Reap` expressions look something like this:

```
Reap[(*... some code ... *)][[2]] /. {r_} :> r
```

I'm not fond of that boilerplate.

**Alternative?**

I am not advocating the removal of `Reap` -- it has valuable uses cases, say, classifying terms in algebraic expressions.  Rather, I would welcome the addition of another function that handles the common case of building up a single list procedurally.  Just as `FirstCase` provides a convenient notation for a very common use of `Cases`.  Perhaps something along these lines:

```
SetAttributes[reapList, HoldAll]
reapList[{sow_}, body_] :=
  Module[{bag, sow}
  , bag = Internal`Bag[]
  ; sow[v_] := Internal`StuffBag[bag, v]
  ; body
  ; Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
  ]

reapList[{sow}
, Scan[If[OddQ[#], sow[#]]&, Range[10]]
]
(* {1, 3, 5, 6, 9} *)

reapList[{sow}
, Scan[If[# > 100, sow[#]]&, Range[10]]
]
(* {} *)
```

`reapList` is notationally convenient when building up a single list. It also is safer to use in library code where the dynamic extent established by `Reap` could extend into user code causing user calls to `Sow` to wreak havoc with the library function.

Comment: Nice. Competing answers. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I confess that my answer is mostly motivated by the need to vent about `Reap` :D

Comment: It turns out my primary use of `Reap` was superseded by `GroupBy`, the `Association` thing not withstanding.

Comment: I these kinds of suggestions are exactly what @TaliesinBeynon was hoping for

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly the explanation I was looking for. I simply didn't think of trying patterns which match more than one tag. One more case which explains the necessity of the additional wrapping just came to my mind: For a pattern which doesn't match, `Reap` produces an empty list - a place holder. This would not be possible without the additional level of wrapping.

Answer (score 6):

The form of `Reap` your using is

```
Reap[expr, p:{pat1, pat2, ...}]
```

where each pattern generates a separate list in the answer. For instance, from the docs,

```
Reap[
 Sow[1, RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 100]], 
 {_?Negative, _?NonNegative}, 
 #1 -> Total[#2] &
] // Last
(* {
 {-1 -> 4, -3 -> 5, -2 -> 5, -9 -> 6, -4 -> 4, -7 -> 3, -8 -> 3, -5 ->8, -6 -> 1}, 
 {1 -> 7, 0 -> 7, 6 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 2, 7 -> 12, 2 -> 3, 5 -> 2, 3 -> 6}
} 
*)
```

So, each pattern is applied to the entire list, and the results for each are returned in a separate sub-list. In you case, you first have the pattern `tag1`, which only matches one thing, so it is put into a sub-list. The same thing happens for the second pattern, `tag2`, giving your nested result. In essence, this is what is going on:

```
Reap[sowstuff, #][[2]]& /@ {tag1, tag2}
(* {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}}} *)
```

To "fix" this, you merge the two patterns:

```
Reap[sowstuff, (tag1 | tag2), Rule] // Last
(* {tag1 -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, tag2 -> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}} *)
```

where `Rule` was included to emphasize the difference.