# Function that returns the second argument of Reap

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I'm trying to create a function that returns only the second argument of Reap. Here's my naive guess of how it would go : `Reap2[x_]:= Flatten[Reap[x][[2]],1]`

However, even when X contains `Sow`, my function always returns empty.
I've made a simplified version here, which shows what I mean.

```
Reap[Sow[1]]
{1, {{1}}}

Clear[Reap2];
Reap2[x_] := Reap[x]
Reap2[Sow[1]]
{1, {}}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? How would I go about building this function?

Comment: You are only missing `HoldFirst`.  Try:  `SetAttributes[Reap2, HoldFirst]`.

Comment: `Reap` is not a simple function. It is closer to scoping constructs in spirit. It has a `Hold` attribute, so that the code evaluates only inside of it, but not before being passed. You need to set `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst` attribute to your `Reap2`, if you want it to behave properly.

Comment: Lokdal, I am glad you have your solution but there is no need to include it in the question.  In fact it is unnecessary clutter and draws attention away from the Accepted answer.  By the way I do not believe that you will need to use both `Join` and `Flatten`.

Comment: Mr.Wizard : edited accordingly! And you're right, for my specific need I had to use Flatten because I Sow lists, and using Join removed the structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is lack of `HoldFirst` in attributes of your function, `Sow` is being called too early otherwise before `Reap` can capture

```
ClearAll[reap2]
SetAttributes[reap2,HoldFirst]
reap2[x_]:=Join @@ Reap[x][[2]]
```

idea to use `Join@@` taken from @Mr.Wizard from here [What is shorthand way of Reap list that may be empty because of zero Sow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/what-is-shorthand-way-of-reap-list-that-may-be-empty-because-of-zero-sow)

Comment: This is what I like to see: new user jump in and write up answers! +1

Comment: @halirutan Yep, same feelings here. +1.

Comment: agree with @Mr.Wizard should use HoldFirst instead of HoldAll

Comment: From a profile:  "An irritating idiot with a high opinion of himself. Best ignored." -- lol -- okay, we've all been duly warned. :^)