# Why application of "Reap" in the forms of prefix and suffix does not work?

Tags: functions

I have been believing in Wolfram language that several forms of application of a function are equivalent:

```
f[a]
f@a
a//f
a~f~b (*for more than one argument*)
```

But why the last two rows of codes do not work below?

```
x := Sum[Sow[i^2, (-1)^i], {i, 10}]

Reap[x]
Reap@x
x // Reap
x~Reap~_
x~Reap~{-1, 1}
Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &@x
x // Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &
```

which give

```
{385, {{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}, {4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}
{385, {{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}, {4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}
{385, {{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}, {4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}
{385, {{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}, {4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}
{385, {{{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}}, {{4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}}
{385, {{}, {}}}
{385, {{}, {}}}
```

Are there some peculiarities when `Reap` meets `Function`?

Comment: try  `Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &@Unevaluated[x]` and 
`Unevaluated[x] // Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &`

Comment: @kglr It works, thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, maybe [Function that returns the second argument of Reap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68949/function-that-returns-the-second-argument-of-reap/68950#68950)?

Comment: @kglr Better than I had remembered existing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of the different attributes between [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and a (default) [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).  Observe that `Reap` has [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html):

```
Attributes[Reap]
```

> ```
> {HoldFirst, Protected}
> ```

Without this the `Sow` expression is evaluated *before* `Reap` ever has a chance to see it.  Adding `HoldFirst` to your `Function` will fix this:

```
Function[, Reap[#, {-1, 1}], HoldFirst] @ x
x // Function[x, Reap[x, {-1, 1}], HoldFirst]
```

> ```
> {385, {{{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}}, {{4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}}
>
> {385, {{{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}}, {{4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}}
> ```

Note that the first line uses an undocumented but longstanding syntax.  This syntax is especially useful when you want to use [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) in a `Function` with attributes.  See:

- [Pure function with attributes of arbitrary number of arguments: Is it possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `Unevaluated[x]` to prevent evaluation of `x` before it is passed to  `Reap[#, {-1, 1}]`:

```
Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &@Unevaluated[x]
Unevaluated[x] // Reap[#, {-1, 1}] &
```

both give

> {385, {{1, 9, 25, 49, 81}, {4, 16, 36, 64, 100}}}