# Why is Reap result nested?

Tags: syntax, output, language-design, sow-reap

A minimal (toy) example for my question:

```
    i= 1;
    Reap[Do[Sow[i = (i + 1)^2], {4}]]
(* {Null, {{4, 25, 676, 458329}}} *)
```

I presume the entire result is a list with first entry `Null` because the `Do` loop returns `Null`.

But why is the result of the `Reap` the nested list `{{4, 25, 676, 458329}}` rather than just `{4, 25, 676, 458329}`?

An even simpler example:

```
    Reap[Sow[i = 2]]
(*  2, {{2}}} *)
```

Why last entry `{{2}}` instead of `{2}` (or perhaps even just plain `2`)?

Comment: The second element is a list of lists because there may be several different tags sown.

Comment: Example `Reap[Sow[1, {x, y}]; Sow[2, y]; Sow[3, x], _, tag]`

Comment: Related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57929/return-value-of-reap-when-using-tags)

Comment: Some related answers of mine which I hope may be helpful: [(6415)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6415/121),
[(31076)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31076/121),
[(44118)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44118/121),
[(67625)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67625/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To summarize the comments into an answer:

The second element is a list of lists because there may be several different tags sown. For example,

```
Reap[Sow[1, x]; Sow[2, y]; result]

(* {result, {{1}, {2}}} *)
```

Another example by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius),

```
Reap[Sow[1, {x, y}]; Sow[2, y]; Sow[3, x], _, tag]

(* {3, {tag[x, {1, 3}], tag[y, {1, 2}]}} *)
```

See also this previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57929/return-value-of-reap-when-using-tags) pointed out by [Ymareth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/880/ymareth).